# Editing geometry is messing up my UV

Tags: uv, edit-mode

[image: Before][image: After]

I must be missing something very obvious, but after googling around for longer than I'm willing to admit I still can't figure out how to preserve my UV while editing my geometry. In the attached example I show a vertex splitting into 4 in the UV Editor after being moved up in the 3D viewport on Edit Mode.

I **need** that in order to add shape keys to my model.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Found it. Gotta uncheck 'Correct Face Attributes' in the Toolbar.